# Update thread across all threads

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, volatile

I have multiple threads and a variable. I set this variable to a string value in one string and then use that latest variable in another thread. However it doesn't seem to be updating across threads. I have set the variable as

```
public volatile String userInput = null;
```

The variable is used as:

```
Server s = new Server();
while (s.userInput==null)
    {
    }
System.out.println(s.userInput);
command = s.userInput;
```

Waits until the variable has a value, then assigns a variable in the current class to it. The variable is set in the Server class.

Does it need something else? or is volatile wrong? Thanks, much appreciated :)

Comment: You should probably show us where you use this field.

Comment: you could even use static fields to share data members across thread objects

Comment: Find the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214331/synchronize-write-access-to-volatile-field-cheap-read-write-block?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: It seems like you have a difference instance per thread.

Comment: @cooperHawk Making it static has worked, cheers

Comment: Can you post the code? I am not able to figure out how are you setting the value of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

@pokeairguy welcome :) ..

by the way volatile tells JVM in a way that the field value must not be cached .. whenever a write occurs it must be updated wherever referenced= therefore **volatile**

and your code made different volatile members per object i.e they were different for each object so no sharing ..

that is why using static was the way to share data members across thread objects