# Is this a good case for using a volatile variable in java?

Tags: java

I have a  thread that listens to an incoming stream of strings from a server. I have a class that I set the incoming string to:

```
public class StreamData {

    protected static volatile String INCOMING_STRING = null;

    public static String getIncomingString() {
        return INCOMING_STRING;
    }

    public static void setIncomingString(String IncomingString) {
        INCOMING_STRING = IncomingString;
    }
}
```

So in my `Thread1` I have `setIncomingString(String IncomingString)`
Now I have another thread `Thread2` that listens to client requests and sends back data by calling first `getIncomingString()`.

The reason I used volatile here is because I am sharing data between 2 threads and I read that volatile variables should be used in this case. Is my idea correct?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `volatile` here, but note that it only ensures the field can be consistently read across threads. It won't give you a free pass against any other kind of concurrency issues (race hazards, deadlocks, etc.)

Comment: You could also use a `BlockingQueue`. look [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html#java-blockingqueue-example) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one sense it is safe.  A thread that calls `getIncomingString` is guaranteed to see the string most recently written by a call to `setIncomingString`.

However ...

It is not clear that this property is sufficient for `StreamData` to be useful.  For example:

1. Thread1 receives a string and calls `setIncomingString`.
2. Thread1 received a second string and calls `setIncomingString` again.
3. Thread2 calls `getIncomingString` ... and gets the second string.

In the above sequence, the first string has been lost, and neither thread is aware of that.

The `StreamData` class is not going to allow you to "stream" the data.  To achieve *that*, what you need is something like a classic queue class where:

- one thread adds strings and the second thread removes them,
- the first thread blocks if the queue is too full,
- the second thread blocks if the queue is empty, and
- neither thread has to execute a "busy loop" to wait for something to happen.

That can't be implemented using just `volatile`.

Comment: I am only interested in the latest string, but thanks for the alternative "queue" solution! will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be thread save. `volatile` on single object (`static` in your case) and one `set` operation  will be enough to prevent multithread issues. Please, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214331/synchronize-write-access-to-volatile-field-cheap-read-write-block) to clear your understanding about `volatile` property and thread save operations.